# Way to select pandas series with required data_type and apply function in place

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many `float64`, `int8` and `object` datatype columns/series. I want to apply a set of functions based on the datatype, but in place. I am unable to do that. I can separate out the columns based on `data_type` and concat them back based on a index. But I was wondering if there is a way to do it without separation.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 3))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2'],
                        'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']},
                        index=[0, 1, 2] )
df=pd.concat ([df1,df2])
df.dtypes
# 0    float64
# 1    float64
# 2    float64
# A     object
# B     object
# dtype: object
```

`df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).apply(lambda x: x*x).dropna()`

Gets me a new data frame.

`df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]) = df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).apply(lambda x: x*x)`

`SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`

Ridiculous attempt to try and do it place. I realized I'm asking assignment to map 'lhs' to 'rhs' automatically, when there are different series on both sides.

Is there a way to do this operation in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think should be 'float64' rather than 'int64'

```
df.loc[:,df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).columns] = df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).apply(lambda x: x*x)
df
Out[117]: 
          0         1         2    A    B
0  0.232743  0.107359  1.512470  NaN  NaN
1  0.831272  1.935141  0.010660  NaN  NaN
2  0.017718  0.078454  0.056315  NaN  NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN   A0   B0
1       NaN       NaN       NaN   A1   B1
2       NaN       NaN       NaN   A2   B2
```

More info `update`

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).apply(lambda x: x*x))
df
Out[139]: 
          0         1         2    A    B
0  0.074513  0.679018  0.070407  NaN  NaN
1  0.748732  0.004991  0.591979  NaN  NaN
2  0.006658  1.934269  0.106463  NaN  NaN
0       NaN       NaN       NaN   A0   B0
1       NaN       NaN       NaN   A1   B1
2       NaN       NaN       NaN   A2   B2
```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand why. I see that right-side statement is same, left is different. I ran `df.loc[:,df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]).columns] ` and it gives a dataframe just like `df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"])`

Comment: @Poppinyoshi df.select_dtypes(include = ["float64"]) this is not assign function for dataframe .

Comment: @Poppinyoshi If you want the original dataframe changed , you can not do assign for the subset(In your original code), should from .loc or .iloc etc ..

Comment: So do you suggest I read up on `loc` in the docs, and find out why exactly is it different from subsetting a dataset using a `method` such as `select_dtypes`. I know that `loc` works on rows, and you have used a slice with `loc`, where `select_dtypes` worked on columns.